# UIWebView dynamic html to template

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

Hi I want to create a (internal or external)html template for data I recieve from an xml request. This is the code I have and it's working fine so far:

```
    NSString* desc = [screenData.jsonVars objectForKey:@"descriptionTXT"];
    NSString* title = [screenData.jsonVars objectForKey:@"titleTXT"];
    NSString* day = [screenData.jsonVars objectForKey:@"dayTXT"];
    NSString* month = [screenData.jsonVars objectForKey:@"monthTXT"];
    NSString* url = [screenData.jsonVars objectForKey:@"dataURL"];
    NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"<html>"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                                   "body { background-color:transparent; font-family:Marker Felt; font-size:44;color:#fff;}"
                                   "</style>"
                                   "<body>"
                                   "<p style=\"text-align:center;font-size:65px;\">%@</p>"
                                   "<div style=\"color:#ff9900;margin:5px;padding:10px;\">%@ &nbsp;%@</div>"
                                   "<div style=\"color:#000;background:#DBDBDB;margin:5px;padding:10px;\">%@</div>"
                                   "<div style=\"color:#000;background:#ff9900;margin:5px;padding:10px;\"><a href=\"%@\">Go to website</a></div>"
                                   "</body></html>", title, day, month, desc, url];
    [BT_debugger showIt:self:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is the HTML: %@", htmlContentString]];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Now I want to take out the html and read that from a file external or internal. For example in template1.html

As you can see it's dynamic (it's data) and I want to keep it that way.

Anyone suggestions on this
Thanks in advance,

D.

Answer (score 6):

The answer that's using `+stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:` with `NSMutableString` should be using `-replaceOccurrencesOfString:` instead. Also, `NSBundle -pathForResource:` returns a path, not the actual contents of the file. Here's an example that works:

**Template**

```
<!-- template.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                font-family:"Helvetica Neue UltraLight",helvetica,verdana;
                margin-left:0;
                margin-right:0;
            }
            section{
                padding-left:5px;
                padding-right:5px;
                font-size:12px;
            }
            h1{
                font-size: 16px;
                padding-left:5px;
            }
            img{
                display: block;
                 /* 4:3 dimensions */
                width: 220px;
                height:165px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>[[[name]]]</h1>
       <img src="[[[image]]]" alt="" />
       <section>
            <p>[[[full_description]]]</p>
       </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code**

```
// load the template
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"template" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *template = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithString:template];

// make substitutions
[html replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"[[[name]]]" withString:self.building.name options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)];
[html replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"[[[image]]]" withString:self.building.image options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)];
[html replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"[[[full_description]]]" withString:self.building.fulldescription options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)];

// load html string into webView
[self.webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//set local path for file
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
    [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],
    @"myTemplate.html"];

//convert htmlContentString to raw data
NSData *data = [htmlContentString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//write data to file
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

//display file in webview
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: filePath]]];
```

Comment: Hi erkanyildiz, thanks for talking time to answer my question. But how does it know how and which variables it has to use in the html?

Comment: I mean: how and where to use the NSString values for title, day, month, desc, url ???

Comment: Actually I don't get what you exactly want. You receive some XML data, convert it to some HTML, and display it in a uiwebview. So what do you want in addition to those?

Comment: Hi Erkanyldiz,Sorry if I confuse you. The code I showed above is working fine. I want the html of that code to move to an external file. Let's assume that I want it to put on my server. That way I can make edits to the html without rebuilding my project every time in Xcode. My xml data is set to the NSString variables (title, day, month, desc, url). Ofcourse they need to be added too. Problem is I don't know how. At this time (with the internal/inline html in the code above) I get every NSString by adding them with %@ to the html output. Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Hmm. I get it now. You need to process the xml data on a external web page. You can use clientside(javascript) or webside(php, asp, ...) tools to format the xml into human readable html.

Comment: thanks, so you think it isn't possible the way I want it? I have an xml document that gets parsed by the xml reader. Lot of xml tags are read and a (menu)list (tableview) is generated from some of the xml tags. Then (selectrow) all of them are ported over to a new (web)view and with these I build my detail view (so i don't have to parse it again and works much faster) There has to be a way to do this!! Hope you or someone else has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

## template.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>[[[desc]]]</div>
<div>[[[title]]]</div>
<div>[[[day]]]</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Code

```
NSString *desc = @"descriptionText";
NSString *title = @"titleText";
NSString *day = @"dayText";
NSString *templateString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"template" ofType:@"html"];
NSMutableString *htmlContentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:templateString];
[htmlContentString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[[[desc]]]" withString:desc];
[htmlContentString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[[[title]]]" withString:title];
[htmlContentString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[[[day]]]" withString:day];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
[htmlContentString release];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```